# Synapse : Execute the Magic Command (%run) Notebook from Pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-synapse, spark-notebook, magic-command

The magic commands work perfectly in Notebooks. However, While running the same notebook from the Synapse pipeline, it could not locate the notebook's path.

Appreciate your help

```
{
    "errorCode": "6002",
    "message": "MagicUsageError: Cannot read notebook Externals/Helper. The possible reason is that the notebook doesn't exist. More details please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2173018\n--> PartnerException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.Analytics.SynapseNotebookService.Infrastructure.Exceptions.ClientExceptions.PartnerException' was thrown.",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "sample",
    "details": []
}
```

Comment: If you are using name for reference try using absolute path

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your scenario in my environment and got similar error.
[image]
The cause of error is the path you provided to the `%run` magic command
**`%run` command currently only supports to pass a absolute path**

- If your notebook is not in any folder, you can give path as `%run /notebook name`
- If your notebook is present in any folder you can give path as `%run /folder name/notebook name`

And make sure you publish all the changes.

Here I am calling `Notebook2` from `Notebook1`
[image]

Notebook ran successfully.
[image]

Comment: Wow, It worked. Thank you @PratikLad. Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using GIT you need to publish the notebook first. After that the reference over the pipeline works.

Best regards Gio

Comment: Thank you Gio for your response, It doesn't seem to be working even though all my notebooks and pipeline were committed to my working branch. Any Idea?

Comment: Try to use following syntax for your command %run folder/notebook

Comment: Im not sure what do you mean with working branch? I dont know your project structure but you have to publish your code on the publish branch for example "workspace_publish". Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69904715/azure-synapse-workspace-where-the-scripts-are-published