# Azure Data Factory doesn't create ARM templates in the adf_publish branch

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-data-factory, azure-rm-template, azure-repos

I'm currently setting up a CI/CD structure for an Azure Data Factory Pipeline. The main branch of my development repository has already got a huge number of ressources and linked services.

Tutorials show that usually during the creation of a feature branch, a branch adf_publish is created, containing the ARM template for the feature branches ressources.

In my ADF repository, the adf_publish branch is created, but it is empty except for the README file.

Working in the feature branches, commiting, pull requests etc all work fine, but the ARM templates are still missing.

Does anyone have an idea, what the problem could be?

Thank you all in advance

Comment: I don't think it will create the ARM until you Publish. Just working in main won't do it. This may be worth reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69904715/azure-synapse-workspace-where-the-scripts-are-published/69905368#69905368

Comment: Hm ok, I thought that in all tutorials those files are created before publishing. We will try starting the publish process today, I will then come back with more information. Thanks so far

Comment: The ARM templates are not created until you Publish the ADF as Joel said. But you can create them with an Azure DevOps build pipeline upon every commit if you prefer.  See this page for details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-improvements .  We have done that because it makes the CI/CD work better.

Comment: Thank you all, the solution really was that simple. Problem solved

Comment: Thanks for sharing that Scott. Interesting (and disappointing) that it only applies to ADF and not Synapse.