# what is the difference between ADF UX and ADF service?

Tags: azure-data-factory

While going through documentation for 'source control in ADF', I came across following information in the introduction paragraph.

> By default, **[the Azure Data Factory user interface experience (UX)
> authors directly against the data factory service.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/source-control)** This
> experience has the following limitations:
>
> The Data Factory service doesn't include a repository for storing the
> JSON entities for your changes. The only way to save changes is via
> the Publish All button and all changes are published directly to the
> data factory service.
>
> The Data Factory service isn't optimized for collaboration and
> version control.
>
> The Azure Resource Manager template required to deploy Data Factory
> itself is not included.

from the highlighted phrase of information, what concerns me is how to understand the difference between ADF service and ADF UI. Couldn't find any relevant information over google search.

Would anyone please help me understand. I have attached the web-link for the source of the document.

Thank you for your time and support

Comment: @GregGalloway answer is correct. Here is another answer with some more detail. It is written for Synapse, but the concepts are the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69904715/azure-synapse-workspace-where-the-scripts-are-published/69905368#69905368

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ADF UI is the authoring tool. By default it isn’t connected to Azure DevOps or GitHub for source control. This is called “Live Mode” and changes are saved directly to ADF service (meaning “saved to the server”).

The preferred method of working in the ADF UI is to connect it Azure DevOps or GitHub repos for source control. (The link you provided describes this.) This allows you to save intermediate progress (even if the pipeline won’t validate because it isn’t valid). And it allows you to utilize source control features like branching, merging, pull request approvals, etc. Only when you merge to the main branch and then Publish do the changes get saved to the ADF service. Until then you can debug pipelines including changes you made in your branch. But the version of pipeline that is run from a trigger (like a schedule trigger) is the published version not what’s in the main branch or in your branch.

Comment: that's a very helpful explanation, Greg. Thank you for your support!