# ADF_PUBLISH Branch never seems to sync with my Collab (Master branch) after publishing from Master

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am looking to understand some behavior as I am setting up a CI-CD Azure Data Factory for the first time.

My expectation is this so far:

I have an Pipeline YML file sitting in Master branch that triggers upon detecting changes to ADF_PUBLISH when I hit the publish button in the UI. It succeeds and then loads those changes to the next (UAT) environment as another ADF factory.

In the added image though my ADF_PUBLISH branch is always both ahead and behind but the code within doesn't seem to represent that. These differences are ARM file changes that don't exist in Master... So I guess I just don't understand what is saying or if I should be concerned about it or fix it.

[image]

I've synced adf_publish to master to resolve this but it just happens anyway so I stopped. I don't get errors or anything from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Publish branch is not a regular branch in the sense that it does not contain the same files as your main branch. Instead, it is a JSON representation of the assets. As such, the file and folder structure is very different and a direct comparison will not be very useful. You may find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69904715/azure-synapse-workspace-where-the-scripts-are-published/69905368#69905368) to be useful.